# Can I return back to the natural keyboard after getting used to ergonomic keyboards?

Tags: keyboard, hardware, ergonomics

I hope I ask this question in a right place. Whatever we're all programmers.

I got a new ergonomic keyboard (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000) yesterday. It's a bit wired now, but I'm sure it will be normal in the next few days.

I'm worry if I can work with natural keyboards after that. Is there anybody who worked with such keyboards. Please help me in this regard.

-- EDIT --

I asked this question here because I wana know the programmers (coders) ideas. Writing and editing a program is completely different from writing a letter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not programming-specific, it would be better on http://superuser.com/. (Voting to migrate.)

Comment: I would like to ask this question from programmers not just typists. Writing a program is completely different from others. Superusers are not programmers! Are they?

Comment: Hmm, then maybe http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I think I will get the same result if I ask this question there. They use "discussions on software development" in programmers.stackexchange.com welcome message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that keyboard at home and a normal one at work. I have no difficulty typing on either one. This seems like it would be based on the individual though.